# How to get same results from select as foreach when using GroupBy()

Tags: c#, linq, select, foreach, group-by

I would like to be able to attain the same results that I can get by using foreach on a grouping when using the select method and an anonymous method.

```
    public class ExportData
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Colour { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int Age { get; set; }

        public int Money { get; set; }
    }

    public class ExportDataDictionary
    {
        public IDictionary<string, object> ColumnData { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }
```

Given the two classes above as an example.

I create some data..

```
        var dataCollection = new List<ExportData>
        {
            new ExportData { Name = "Name1", Age = 1, Colour = "Blue", Id = 1, Money = 10 },
            new ExportData { Name = "Name1", Age = 2, Colour = "Red", Id = 2, Money = 20 },
            new ExportData { Name = "Name1", Age = 2, Colour = "Green", Id = 3, Money = 30 },
            new ExportData { Name = "Name2", Age = 1, Colour = "Yellow", Id = 4, Money = 40 },
            new ExportData { Name = "Name3", Age = 2, Colour = "Blue", Id = 5, Money = 50 },
            new ExportData { Name = "Name4", Age = 3, Colour = "Blue", Id = 6, Money = 10 }
        };
```

Next I group this data by, for example, two properties as follows..

```
 var dataGrouping = dataCollection.GroupBy(g => new { g.Name, g.Age });
```

I then create a list of ExportDataDictionaries and foreach through each group in the grouping, creating a new ExportDataDictionary each time and adding both of the keys to the dictionary.

```
        var data = new List<ExportDataDictionary>();

        foreach (var grouping in dataGrouping)
        {
            var datadictionary = new ExportDataDictionary();

            datadictionary.ColumnData.Add("NAME", grouping.Key.Name);
            datadictionary.ColumnData.Add("AGE", grouping.Key.Age);
            data.Add(datadictionary);
        }
```

The result is a collection of 5 ExportDataDictionaries with 2 Columns in each one that contain the pair of keys that correspond to each of the groupings.

My attempt to achieve the same with the Select method is shown below.

```
        var data2 = new List<ExportDataDictionary>();

        var mydata = dataGrouping.Select(d => 
        {
            var datadictionary = new ExportDataDictionary();
            datadictionary.ColumnData.Add("NAME", d.Key.Name);
            datadictionary.ColumnData.Add("AGE", d.Key.Age);
            data2.Add(datadictionary);
            return data2;
        });
```

The result is of the type:

```
mydata = {System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator<System.Linq.IGrouping<<>f__AnonymousType0<string, int>, ConsoleApp2.Program.ExportData>, System.Collections.Generic.List<ConsoleApp2.Program.ExportDataDictionary>>}
```

and it contains 5 items and each item contains 10 dictionaries. The 5 dictionaries that I expect are there with the same values as when using foreach but then there are 2 copies of each. I believe that this must be because it is creating the dictionaries for both of the keys used in the grouping. So, I am wondering how to only do this for one of the keys or just each group in the collection?

The requirement is that `mydata` should contain the same result as obtained by foreach in `data` variable

Any help much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Add `.ToList()` at the end of your last statement remove the  `data2.Add(datadictionary);` statement and only return the datadictionary `return datadictionary;` like this

```
var mydata = dataGrouping.Select(d =>
        {
            var datadictionary = new ExportDataDictionary();
            datadictionary.ColumnData.Add("NAME", d.Key.Name);
            datadictionary.ColumnData.Add("AGE", d.Key.Age);

            return datadictionary;
        }).ToList();
```

I have run your code and checked and saw that `mydata`  contains 5 items, and each item contains 2 `ColumnData` members.

Actually, your Linq query is only executed when you call the `.ToList()` function

Comment: Thank you for the help, unfortunately it does not produce the same results as the foreach. You are correct in that mydata will contain 5 items and each with 5 dictionaries but this is not what I was after. I want only 5 dictionaries with 2 columns.  Someone did post a solution but for some reason their post was removed shortly after - what I needed was to return the datadictionary and not add it to data2 and return that! Thanks again though - appreciate the help ;)

Comment: I have modified the answer according to the requirements.